# Android Webview Click

Tags: android, webview, click

I have a `webview` and I sent a URL. The page display is okay, but I cannot interact with the page displayed. I cannot click the buttons, I have just a front ...
Do you have an idea of the problem?

My code :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_web);
    WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    myWebView.loadUrl("www.google.com");       
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add onclick to webview with the following method:

```
webView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        public final static int FINGER_RELEASED = 0;
        public final static int FINGER_TOUCHED = 1;
        public final static int FINGER_DRAGGING = 2;
        public final static int FINGER_UNDEFINED = 3;

        private int fingerState = FINGER_RELEASED;


        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

            switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    if (fingerState == FINGER_RELEASED) fingerState = FINGER_TOUCHED;
                    else fingerState = FINGER_UNDEFINED;
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    if(fingerState != FINGER_DRAGGING) {
                        fingerState = FINGER_RELEASED;

                        // Your onClick codes
                       Toast.makeText(WebActivity.this,"Click Detected",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();            

                    }
                    else if (fingerState == FINGER_DRAGGING) fingerState = FINGER_RELEASED;
                    else fingerState = FINGER_UNDEFINED;
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    if (fingerState == FINGER_TOUCHED || fingerState == FINGER_DRAGGING) fingerState = FINGER_DRAGGING;
                    else fingerState = FINGER_UNDEFINED;
                    break;

                default:
                    fingerState = FINGER_UNDEFINED;

            }

            return false;
        }
    });
```

If there is a button inside webview, the webpage that you are displaying inside the webview will handle that.You cannot get that callback.

Comment: display a ttoast on the portion  // Your onClick codes in the above code.

Comment: I can't click in my web view, i use your method but it's not working :/

Comment: paste your code in pastebin and give me the link...let me see

Answer (score 1):

try this code I think it will work:

```
WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```